# Java.exe version independent path

Tags: java, windows, service, installshield

I need to reference java.exe in a service bin path. To find java.exe I make two steps:

1. read java version: SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment (CurrentVersion)
2. read : SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\ (JavaHome)

then I get a path like this: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201

The problem is: If I update Java, then this path is not exisiting anymore.

I found that the java.exe is also present here:
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

BUT: the file is not here in any case/on any system, but I do not know why.

Does anyone has an idea how to work around this issue?

Comment: Just have a configuration file where your configure the current java path. Trying to find the path in the service itself will bite you sooner or later, because just because it found a java path, it doesn't mean it should use that. When you have more than one version installed, which one should it use?

Comment: Whenever there is this type of dependency I will install the Java bins to the local install directory and use those. The version dependency is an ongoing problem with Java.